# Internal PCI Motorola sm56 Modem Doesn't Work on Ubuntu 13.04 32 bits with Smartlink Drivers

Tags: modem

I have an internal PCI Motorola SM56 modem. Until Ubuntu 12.10 I was able to make it work on 32 bits by installing packages sl-modem-source, sl-modem-daemon, dkms and gnome-ppp (with all the dependencies) and Smartlink drivers were able to make the modem work. Now, after installing Ubuntu 13.04 32 bits in the same Pc, same modem (it works fine on other OSes) now the modem now doesn't work on Ubuntu 13.04. What changed? What can I do to make my modem work on Ubuntu 13.04?

Comment: Have you aachieved something?, i have the same problem!!. Please any body can help us!

Answer (score 0):

The following procedure worked for me with Ubuntu 14.04, Mint 17.0 and Mint 17.1:

```
sudo apt-get install sl-modem-source sl-modem-daemon
sudo apt-get install module-assistant
sudo module-assistant auto-install sl-modem
sudo depmod -a (this updates the list of available modules)
sudo gedit /etc/default/sl-modem-daemon
```

Insuring that `SLMODEMD_COUNTRY=USA` (or whatever country you are in)

```
sudo modprobe slamr
```

Unfortunately, this stopped working with Linux Mint 17.2, which has a different kernel.